# Apache Giraph SendMessage

Tags: giraph

I am writing a distributed clustering algorithm using Apache Giraph. In the compute() method I need to access the value that each neighbors sent plus the weight of the edge between the current vertex and the neighbor who sent that message. However, the only message type that I see in the Giraph examples are single-type message (DoubleWritable, IntWritable, etc), which can only passes the value but not the sender information,

How can we access the sender information or the edge information as well?

For instance, in the above code we can get the value of each message, but we do not know which node sent this value to the current node.

```
public void compute(Iterator<DoubleWritable> msgIterator) {
    ...
    double minDist = isSource() ? 0d : Double.MAX_VALUE;
    while (msgIterator.hasNext()) {
        // Get who sent this message, how?
        minDist = Math.min(minDist, msgIterator.next().get());
    }
    ...
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: A code example might attract more attention.

Comment: Thanks Andres, did that.

Comment: You can certainly write your own `Writable` implementation for your needs. Please don't use the Hadoop tag if you're not relating to Hadoop at all.

Answer (score 4):

I agree to Thomas Jungblut; writing your own `Writable` is probably the best (and easiest) solution.

I recently wrote a custom `Writable` called `IntPairWritable` which simply holds two Integers. Here's my code.

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.giraph.utils.IntPair;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configurable;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;

public class IntPairWritable extends IntPair implements Writable, Configurable {

    private Configuration conf;

    public IntPairWritable() {
        super(0, 0);
    }

    public IntPairWritable(int fst, int snd) {
        super(fst, snd);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput input) throws IOException {
        super.setFirst(input.readInt());
        super.setSecond(input.readInt());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput output) throws IOException {
        output.writeInt(super.getFirst());
        output.writeInt(super.getSecond());
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConf() {
        return this.conf;
    }

    @Override
    public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
        this.conf = conf;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.getFirst() + "," + super.getSecond();
    }
}
```

---

Your `Writable` class could look just similar. Maybe like

```
public class RetraceableWritable<I extends Writable, D extends Writable> implements Writable, Configurable {
    private I senderId;
    private D data;
    ...
```

...and so on.

---

- Note 1: the default constructor must always exist to ensure that Hadoop can create an instance of your class.
- Note 2: Giraph seems to like it when everything is `configurable` so implementing this interface is a good idea.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As darefilz mentioned, writing your own Writable class would be the best option.
There is an example provided "verifyMessages.java" in giraph examples where a customized message class is used.

Here's the link
https://apache.googlesource.com/giraph/+/old-move-to-tlp/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/examples/VerifyMessage.java